# Bidirectional mapping of entities in Hibernate and spring mvc

Tags: mysql, spring, entity-framework, hibernate

I am trying to map two entities User(userid,name,password,address) and Role(roleId,roleName).
I am trying to do bidirectional OneToMany mapping between User and Role.

My User entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="UserRole",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
)
public Set<Role> role;
```

My Role entity:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name="UserRole",
        joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
)
private User user;
```

Now the corresponding intermediate table created in the database has following attributes.

userrole-> attributes( user_userId,ROLE_ID,USER_ID )

Now when i add set of items to a user. ROLE_ID and USER_ID of userrole table gets populated but user_userId remain null. What is the purpose of user_useerId.Should i manully make it primary key in the table user_userId?

**UPDATE**:

i did the following editing in Role entity

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name="UserRole",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
)
private User user;
```

And now when i checked the table in the database, the "userrole" table is perfectly ok and contains only (USER_ID,ROLE_ID)

I want to know why shouldn't i map two entities though this way?

Comment: remove the `@JoinTable` declaration on your `Role` entity as you have already declared it in `User` entity

Comment: I want the mapping to be bidirectional between user and role.    Can you tell me what is the purpose of user_userId and how it got automatically created??

Comment: If you need bidirectional then adding `user` property in `Role` entity with `@MantToOne` declaration is sufficient, so no need of having `@JoinTable` once again.

Comment: now coming to `user_userId`, in your `Role` entity you have declared the Join Table annotation and this annotation needs two column names, but you have provided one with name `ROLE_ID` and ignore the second name which is `inverseJoinColumns` that is pointing to `User` entity, so hibernate creates a column with name as combination of the entity name in lower case (which is `user` in your case) then the identifier in that entity separated by underscore (which is `userId` I guess based on column name). So finally the column name became `user_userId`.

Comment: added as answer for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `User` entity you have declared `@OneToMany` with `Role` and also given details about the Join table using `@JoinTable`.

So if you need `bidirectional` between `User` and `Role` entities, then adding `user` property in `Role` entity with `@ManyToOne` declaration is sufficient, so no need of having `@JoinTable` once again.

Now coming to `user_userId` - in your `Role` entity you have declared the `@JoinTable` annotation and this annotation needs two column names for Join Table.

```
@JoinTable(
        name="JoinTableName",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_NAME_FOR_THIS_ENTITY"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID_NAME_FOR_THE_MAPPING_ENTITY")
)
```

but you have provided one with name `ROLE_ID` and ignore the second name which is `inverseJoinColumns` that points to `User` entity.

```
@JoinTable(
        name="UserRole",
        joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
)
```

so hibernate should make a guess about the column name for `inverseJoinColumns`, so it creates a column with name as combination of the entity name in lower case (which is `user` in your case) then the identifier in that entity separated by underscore (which is `userId` I guess based on column name). So finally the column name becomes `user_userId`.

**Update:**

If you need bidirectional relationship then you need to declare your entities like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Role> role;
```

Here you are telling to hibernate that `User` entity has one-to-many relationship with `Role` entity and the relationship is bi-directional and the `Role` entity has a property called `user`.

Now in your `Role` entity you will give details about the `JoinTable` like this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name="UserRole",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
)
private User user;
```

The property name `user` in `Role` entity should match with the `mappedBy` attribute that you have declared in your `User` entity for the `@OneToMany` annotation. Adding the `user` field to `Role` entity makes the relationship bi-directional.

Comment: @bablu, I have added details under my update section that tells how to use `mappedby` attribute in case of bi-directional relationship.

Answer (score 1):

A (typical) bidirectional mapping has one side that is maintaining the relationship and the other side follows this relation ship.

This mean when you modifiy the maintaining side of the relation ship and save this change, then it gets stored in the database. While when you modifiy the following side, then nothing gets changed in the database. (it gets only updated when you load the entity).

A mapping would looks like:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user") //mappedBy makes this side to the following side
  public Set<Role> role;
  ...
}


@Entity
public class Role {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  //@JoinTable... when you need it 
  private User user;
  ...
}
```

---

But this mapping is strange: because it mean that every User can have serveral roles, but each role belongs to exactly one user. -- If this is not intended, then switch `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` or move over to `ManyToMany`